# one word for shocking and clever?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage

I am looking for one word which means both shocking and clever.

Example sentence: Shocking and clever revenge story.

Comment: **awe·some** ˈôsəm *adjective* 1. extremely impressive or daunting; inspiring great admiration, apprehension, or fear. "*the awesome power of the atomic bomb*". http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/awesome **See also**: http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/awesome Not the informal word that means *cool*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [brilliant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/brilliant?s=t). It conveys that someone is amazed at the person's cleverness, as in saying, "You are absolutely brilliant!" or "Brilliant solution. Good work."

You might also consider [cunning](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cunning?s=t) if by shocking you mean scandalous. 
You could also try [ingenious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ingenious?s=t), but it does not convey shock as well as brilliant or cunning.

Comment: What about goosebumps? hehe:)

Answer (score 1):

How about [fabulous](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fabulous)? For example, when Simon Cowell thinks a performance is shocking and clever, he would say "That's fabulous!".

Other words I can think of are dramatic, sensational, terrific, phenomenal, magnificent, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *[edgy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/edgy)* is the word you are looking for:-

> (meaning 3). Daring, provocative, or trend-setting: an exhibition of edgy photographs; an edgy menu.

or

> (meaning 3). innovative, or at the cutting edge, with the concomitant qualities of intensity and excitement

Comment: Does it sound good?- What is the most edgy real life revenge story you have ever heard?

Comment: @Mohit, in my opinion it sounds terrible; typical teenager slang as commonly used today. I suggest it because it is widespread, particularly in the arty world.